# Unable to test Spring Boot Rest Controller (stack trace attached)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write tests for my Rest controller. I followed this guide here: https://www.javachinna.com/spring-boot-rest-controller-junit-tests-mockito/ and tried to apply it to my own setup. The application works fine, I just need to know how to write the tests.

Here is the stack trace I am getting:

```
2022-03-23 13:33:12.567  INFO 3957714 --- [           main] dev.tdwl.controller.AuthControllerTests  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-23 13:33:12.962  WARN 3957714 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2022-03-23 13:33:12.967  INFO 3957714 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-23 13:33:12.986 ERROR 3957714 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in dev.tdwl.controller.AuthController required a bean of type 'dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.

2022-03-23 13:33:12.990 ERROR 3957714 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@3e27ba32] to prepare test instance [dev.tdwl.controller.AuthControllerTests@5c77053b]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) [spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 89 common frames omitted


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 ...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

...


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Here is my `AuthControllerTests.java`

```
package dev.tdwl.controller;

import dev.tdwl.services.UserService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {AuthController.class, UserService.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AuthControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = "testaccount@test.com", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "userService")
    void testAuthenticationCheckValid() {
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/auth/check")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `AuthController.java`

```
package dev.tdwl.controller;


import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import dev.tdwl.model.AuthenticationRequest;
import dev.tdwl.model.CategoryLists;
import dev.tdwl.model.JwtResponse;
import dev.tdwl.model.User;
import dev.tdwl.repository.CategoryListsRepository;
import dev.tdwl.repository.UserRepository;
import dev.tdwl.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import dev.tdwl.services.UserDetailsImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Collections;

@RestController
public class AuthController {

    private final CategoryListsRepository categoryRepo;
    private final UserRepository userRepo;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(UserRepository repository, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder encoder, JwtUtils jwtUtils, CategoryListsRepository categoryRepo) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepo = repository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
        this.categoryRepo = categoryRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/auth/check")
    public ResponseEntity<?> verifyLogin() {
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (userDetails.getId() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetails);
    }

    @PostMapping("/auth/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getEmail(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, user.getUsername(), user.getId()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/auth/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateClient(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        String email = authenticationRequest.getEmail();
        String password = authenticationRequest.getPassword();

        User newUser = new User(email, encoder.encode(password));

        try {
            userRepo.save(newUser);
            CategoryLists newList = new CategoryLists(newUser.getId(), Collections.emptyList());
            categoryRepo.save(newList);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException | MongoException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully!");
    }
}
```

Here is my `UserRepository.java`

```
package dev.tdwl.repository;

import dev.tdwl.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    @Query("{email:'?0'}")
    User findUserByEmail(String email);

    @Query("{id:'?0'}")
    User findUserById(String Id);

    long count();
}
```

If anyone has any resources for learning how to do this with modern practices, I would appreciate any and all knowledge passed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a public default constructor (one without a parameters) in AuthController.

Then create a method with annotation @PostConstruct to initialize your AuthController with values that it needs to work properly.

I personally prefer dependency injection through setters because it's easier to create test in that way.

Here you have a nice example of how to do dependency injection with setters: https://www.amitph.com/spring-setter-injection-example/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How then do I inject the dependencies like `AuthenticationManager` into it via the public construct? All the Spring documentation I've read on constructor injection doesn't show this method AFAIK.

Comment: it should be done automatically like in constructor

Comment: Only difference is that it will be done after constuctor method was called. Read that link in answer, it should explain it better

Comment: I see, so I will have a setter for each dependency?

Comment: exactly like that. It's not ideal but if you will be doing a lot of tests then it's best way

Comment: Alright, I added setters for each of the dependencies, now I get two different errors (it will either be one or the other when running): `Parameter 0 of method setAuthenticationManager in dev.tdwl.controller.AuthController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.`

or the same error but with `PasswordEncoder`. I did not add a public constructor because my `AuthController` does not require any parameters other than dependencies.

Comment: if you don't need one then maybe create ```@MockBean PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder``` in your test class. But I'm not 100% sure if it will work. It should mock your bean and automatically inject it where it's needed

Comment: Funny enough, if I add `@MockBean` for all of `AuthControllers` dependencies in my test, I can reverse my code back to the constructor injection and get the same error as the setters gives me: 

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(setupBefore=TEST_METHOD, userDetailsServiceBeanName="userService", value="testaccount@test.com")`